# "No tests were found!!! " in cmake tutorial step 4

Tags: c++, cmake

The contens of CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

# set the project name and version
project(Tutorial VERSION 1.0)

# specify the C++ standard
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)

# should we use our own math functions
option(USE_MYMATH "Use tutorial provided math implementation" ON)

# configure a header file to pass some of the CMake settings
# to the source code
configure_file(TutorialConfig.h.in TutorialConfig.h)

# add the MathFunctions library
if(USE_MYMATH)
  add_subdirectory(MathFunctions)
  list(APPEND EXTRA_LIBS MathFunctions)
endif()

# add the executable
add_executable(Tutorial tutorial.cxx)

target_link_libraries(Tutorial PUBLIC ${EXTRA_LIBS})

# add the binary tree to the search path for include files
# so that we will find TutorialConfig.h
target_include_directories(Tutorial PUBLIC
                           "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}"
                           )

install(TARGETS Tutorial DESTINATION bin)
install(FILES "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/TutorialConfig.h"
  DESTINATION include
  )


enable_testing()

# does the application run
add_test(NAME Runs COMMAND Tutorial 25)

# does the usage message work?
add_test(NAME Usage COMMAND Tutorial)
set_tests_properties(Usage
  PROPERTIES PASS_REGULAR_EXPRESSION "Usage:.*number"
  )

# define a function to simplify adding tests
function(do_test target arg result)
  add_test(NAME Comp${arg} COMMAND ${target} ${arg})
  set_tests_properties(Comp${arg}
    PROPERTIES PASS_REGULAR_EXPRESSION ${result}
    )
endfunction()

# do a bunch of result based tests
do_test(Tutorial 4 "4 is 2")
do_test(Tutorial 9 "9 is 3")
do_test(Tutorial 5 "5 is 2.236")
do_test(Tutorial 7 "7 is 2.645")
do_test(Tutorial 25 "25 is 5")
do_test(Tutorial -25 "-25 is (-nan|nan|0)")
do_test(Tutorial 0.0001 "0.0001 is 0.01")
```

> Rebuild the application and then cd to the binary directory and run the ctest executable: `ctest -N` and `ctest -VV`. For multi-config generators (e.g. Visual Studio), the configuration type must be specified with the `-C <mode>` flag. For example, to run tests in Debug mode use `ctest -C Debug -VV` from the binary directory (not the Debug subdirectory!). Release mode would be executed from the same location but with a `-C Release`. Alternatively, build the `RUN_TESTS` target from the IDE.

I run the cmake commands like above, but it can not run successfully.

I Rebuild the application and cd to the bin directory, and run

```
ctest -C Debug -VV
```

the rusult is

```
No tests were found!!!
```

What did I miss?

Answer (score 1):

Should be run from the build directory, it's not clear in the tutorial, but if you go to the documentation you can see it.

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/book/mastering-cmake/chapter/Testing%20With%20CMake%20and%20CTest.html

Comment: Usually ( i think due to my little experience) test are run in build directory.

Answer (score 0):

I am in the same position. However I found I could run the tests from my /build dir.
`ctest -n ../install/bin`